# converting iPhone App to iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm starting to convert iPhone App to iPad, the app is a special calculator and has a feel and look like one. on iPhone is to use portrait since it the best fit.

My questions are:

i. when I run it on the iPad do i need to use the whole iPad screen size? I would like just to upscale all my controls size and width by let's say 125% of the original size. How do I check the device screen size and how do I center my calculator to be in the center when running on iPad? currently the iPad is `CGRectMake(0,0,640,1024)` but it may change in the future.

ii. I also like it to adjust accordingly on both orientations of the iPad but only portrait on the iPhone. and I'm not sure how to do it in the most effective-easy way... if you may advice.

my current iPhone code has `.xib` with the different controls but I adjust them all using the 
`-setFrame:CGRectMake(...)` in code, so far I set the `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY` in project settings to run app on both devices but didn't change any of the `-setFrame:CGRectMake(...)` to be dynamic depending on the device.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can ask [UIScreen mainScreen] for its bounds - that gives you the size.

2) You need to respond to the rotation methods in your UIViewController related to rotation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

3) You can use this to find out if your app is running on an iPhone or iPad:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]
```

4) To center the view in a larger view use this code:

```
+ (CGRect)centeredFrameForSize:(CGSize)size inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = rintf((rect.size.width - size.width)/2) + rect.origin.x;
    frame.origin.y = rintf((rect.size.height - size.height)/2) + rect.origin.y;
    frame.size = size;

    return frame;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, if i may it seems that basically i need to adjust size from my iphone then iPad portrait and then also iPad landscape ?  is there some technique that the ipad orientation will adjust my app accordingly automatically or do i need to code for bothe case??  Thanks again

Comment: You can use the "should" method to prevent rotations. But beyond that you have to either setup your views to autoresize in the nib (or in code) or do it after the view rotates. If you use the proper struts and sprints in the nib, you can get auto centering for all aspects on both devices. This is a complex topic so you need to read up more about it.